# How to use an enhanced for loop to iterate through a HashSet that is in another method?

Tags: java, for-loop, static, type-conversion

For my assignment I have been asked to produce the following:

- Creates a `HashMap<String,Integer>`
- Loops over all the words returned by `getWordArray()` and puts each word into the `HashMap` with the number of times it occurs
- Returns `HashMap<String, Integer>`

I have already created a HashSet inside another method called `getWordArray()` but I am struggling to figure out how to make it so that the for loop iterates through the `getWordSet()` method without getting an error "`non-static` method cannot be referenced from a static context". When I am string to return my `HashSet` which was created, I am getting the error "incompatible types:

`HashMap<String, Integer>` cannot be converted to String".

Here is the code:

**WordGroup class**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class WordGroup {

String word;

//Creates constructor which stores a string value in variable "word" and converts this into lower case using the lower case method.
public WordGroup(String aString) {
    this.word = aString.toLowerCase();
}
public String[] getWordArray() {
    String[] wordArray = word.split("-");
    return wordArray;
}


public Set<String> getWordSet(WordGroup secondWordGroup) {

 HashSet<String> newHashSet = new HashSet<>();

for (String word : secondWordGroup.getWordArray())
    newHashSet.add(word);

for (String word : this.getWordArray())
    newHashSet.add(word);
System.out.println(newHashSet);
return newHashSet;

}
public String getWordCounts()  
{
     HashMap<String, Integer> myHashMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
     int loopcounter = 0;
     for (WordGroup it : WordGroup.getWordArray())

     loopcounter = loopcounter +1;
     myHashMap.add(it);
     return myHashMap;
}
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        WordGroup firstWordGroup = new WordGroup("You-can-discover-more-about-a-person-in-an-hour-of-plau-tban-in-a-year-of-conversation");
        WordGroup secondWordGroup = new WordGroup ("When-you-play-play-hard-when-you-work-dont-play-at-all");

    }
```

I have two main queries:

- How do I correctly iterate over the getWordArray method?
- How do I return HashMap of data types  as opposed to being a String?

I cannot see any static methods being used in my WordGroup class so obviously I have some misunderstanding of static somewhere and I understand the second error, I'm just not too sure on how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have tried using this if statement:

```
public Set<String> getWordCounts(WordGroup secondWordGroup)  
{
     HashMap<String,Integer> myMap;

     if (myMap.keySet().contains(getWordArray[i]))
     {    
      myMap.get(getWordArray[i]) +1;
      }
     else 
     {
         myMap.put(getWordArray[i],1);

     }
     return myMap;
}
```

I'm not sure if it is done right but there are multiple errors?

Comment: For the error related to static method, can you make the method non static?
For the error related to the incompatible types, I believe you should be creating a HashMap<String, Integer> instead of a HashSet<String>.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about, I don't see the word static in the WordGroup class at all so I assumed everything is non static?

Comment: I think you want [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896467/putting-words-from-an-array-into-a-hashmap-and-a-hashset)

Comment: ahh right. it shouldnt be `WordGroup.getWordArray()`. correct invokation is just `getWordArray()`

ClassName.MethodName() means you are trying to statically invoke the method. But your method isn't static which is why the error was thrown.

Comment: This must be a question from somebody of the same university who had he same assignment, thanks for linking this to me I'm sure it will be very helpful.

Comment: Ahh I understand now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All:
HashSet cannot have duplicate values in it.
Let say HashSet already has word 'hello' in it. then add('hello') does nothing. HashSet still have only one word 'hello' there.
Use ArrayList instead, if you need to have multiple 'hello' there.

Second where did you find HashMap.add() method? it is not there.

Third: did you cut some pieces of your code?

```
for (WordGroup it : WordGroup.getWordArray())

 loopcounter = loopcounter +1;
```

That for loop does only loopcounter = loopcounter +1;

nothing else.

Go this way:
HasMap has a key as word and value as number of occurencies i.e.

```
HasMap<String,Integer> myMap
```

then when you go through your wordArray (you do not need anything else)

If myMap has a key wordArray[i] increase value associated with it in the map:

```
myMap.put(wordArray[i],myMap.get(wordArray[i]) +1)
```

else put new element

```
myMap.put(wordArray[i],1)
```

I hope you will write other things around it on your own.

EDITED:

```
public class WordGroup {

    String  word;

    // Creates constructor which stores a string value in variable "word" and converts this into lower case using
    // the lower case method.
    public WordGroup(String aString) {

        this.word = aString.toLowerCase();
    }

    public String[] getWordArray() {

        String[] wordArray = word.split("-");
        return wordArray;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getWordCountsMap() {

        HashMap<String, Integer> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String nextWord: this.getWordArray()) {
            if (myHashMap.keySet().contains(nextWord)) {
                myHashMap.put(nextWord, myHashMap.get(nextWord) + 1);
            } else {
                myHashMap.put(nextWord, 1);
            }

        }

        return myHashMap;
    }
}
```

end better to do not create HashMap each time, but do it once in constructor.

```
    public class WordGroup {

    String  word;
    HashMap<String, Integer> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    // Creates constructor which stores a string value in variable "word" and converts this into lower case using
    // the lower case method.
    public WordGroup(String aString) {

        this.word = aString.toLowerCase();
        this.createWordCountsMap();
    }

    public String[] getWordArray() {

        String[] wordArray = word.split("-");
        return wordArray;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getWordCountsMap()
    {
        return this.myHashMap;
    }

    private void createWordCountsMap() {

        for (String nextWord : this.getWordArray()) {
            if (this.myHashMap.keySet().contains(nextWord)) {
                this.myHashMap.put(nextWord, this.myHashMap.get(nextWord) + 1);
            } else {
                this.myHashMap.put(nextWord, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this be put into an if/else statement?

Comment: Yes exactly. You do not need to mess with additional ArrayList. Set is not applicable for duplicate values anyway.

Comment: if (myMap.keySet().contains(wordArray[i]))

Comment: I updated my question and have included the if statement that I'm trying to implement.

Comment: C'mon man... see edited answer. That's all you need. getWordCountsMap() returns HashMap you requested for.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your for loop in getWordCounts() does literraly nothing. You have to surround your code with curly brackets like this

```
 for ( /* single element of structure */ : /* structure on which you iterate */) {
        // what you want to do with this single element
    }
```

The first error you're receiving is about this part of code:

```
WordGroup.getWordArray()
```

You are trying to call static method from class WordGroup instead of calling your non-static method for a given instance of the class. What you wanted to achieve is just getWordArray().

Another mistake is the type of your variable "it" in for loop. getWordArray() returns String[] so single element from this structure will be String, now WordGroup.

You should also familiarize yourself with HashMap methods and note that this structure requires key and value. In your example String is the key and Integer the value.

Answering your second question about printing HashMap, you could use its toString method to convert HashMap object to String and then you can easily print it.